# How to sort an array as per index value using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I need one help.I need to sort array as per its index value using PHP. I am explaining my code below.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 17 [name] => Exhibition ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 16 [name] => Office Space ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 15 [name] => Storage ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 14 [name] => Parking ) )
```

Here this arrays order is different like `0,2,3,1`. I need its index like `0,1,2,3`. Please help me.

Comment: Start with http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: What about `ksort()`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php

Answer (score 2):

`ksort()` is the answer you need.

Answer (score 2):

use [`ksort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php), which sorts an array by its keys.

So I created this dummy $test array
example:

```
array(4) { 
    [0]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["name"]=> string(3) "one" } 
    [3]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> int(4) ["name"]=> string(4) "four" } 
    [1]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> int(2) ["name"]=> string(3) "two" } 
    [2]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> int(3) ["name"]=> string(5) "three" } 
}
```

next ksort() Sorts an array by key, maintaining key to data correlations.

```
ksort($test);
```

Now var_dump gives output

```
array(4) { 
    [0]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["name"]=> string(3) "one" } 
    [1]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> int(2) ["name"]=> string(3) "two" } 
    [2]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> int(3) ["name"]=> string(5) "three" } 
    [3]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> int(4) ["name"]=> string(4) "four" } 
}
```

Comment: I did like `$caArr=ksort($catArr); print_r($caArr);` but its not printing anything.here `$catArr` holds the root array which is given in my post.

Comment: Just use ksort($catArr); print_r($catArr); to achieve the sort then display. Your previous code will do that, and then assign the result of the sort to $caArr as either true (succcess) or false (fail), but unless you're interested in this return value you can simply igore assining it to anything.

Comment: dummy array $test :
array(4) { [0]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["name"]=> string(3) "one" } [3]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> int(4) ["name"]=> string(4) "four" } [1]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> int(2) ["name"]=> string(3) "two" } [2]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> int(3) ["name"]=> string(5) "three" } } 

ksort($test );
var_dump($test);

 output:

array(4) { [0]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["name"]=> string(3) "one" } [1]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> int(2) ["name"]=> string(3) "two" } [2]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> int(3) ["name"]=> string(5) "three" } [3]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> int(4) ["name"]=> string(4) "four" } }

Comment: i'll edit my answer and explain more